# stack overflow code in c for writing exploit

Tags: c, linux, security, shellcode

I am attempting to launch a shell in my Linux environment (BT3) but it keeps seg faulting. The method that I'm using is out of *The Shellcoder's HandBook*. Note that all of this is straight out of the text.

For more reference: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/old-pentesting/15508-stuck-eip-buffer-overflow.html

Comment: You *really* need to provide more information than this.

Comment: @Als Sorry, I hope I'm not being too aggressive in suggesting edits to this question? ("hi i m facing a problem plz help me" doesn't seem necessary...)

Comment: @Chris: No that seems logical, I approved your edit, It needs one more approval to be accepted, someone will approve soon.

Answer (score 3):

Many buffer overflow exploits have been fixed in modern operating system patches.  It's likely you're seg faulting because the operating system is detecting a buffer overrun and killing your process.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a modern kernel then your application is segfaulting because exploiting EIP is easily detectable by the OS. When EIP gets changed or overrun the OS has mechanisms in place to check whether the location EIP is pointing is valid in the virtual memory area. In the case of that exploit that check would fail and the OS would send a SIGKILL or SIGSEGV to your application to prevent any harm from being done.

Comment: you can't disble it unless you find the relevant code in the operating system and remove it which is a bad idea

Comment: i have disabled this but still not able to do it

Comment: I doubt that you've disabled all the places where EIP overflows in the kernel are detected, this is also not the place to ask about how to exploit systems or certain things hence why your question was closed